# How do I install a .crt file in Firefox for Windmill Testing Framework?

Tags: installation, firefox, python, ssl, firefox-extensions

I am trying to use the [Windmill Testing Framework](http://www.getwindmill.com/) over https. When I run `windmill firefox http://www.example.com` the Windmill IDE comes up fine. When I run `windmill firefox https://www.example.com` the IDE fails. (I have installed `pyopenssl` in my Python virtual environment. https failed completely before I did this.)

I suspect that this is because I haven't installed the Certificate Authority (.crt file) for Windmill itself.

The Windmill team provide [instructions for installing the Windmill CA on Windows and Mac](https://github.com/windmill/windmill/wiki/SSL-Support), but not Linux, let alone Ubuntu :(

The instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/certificates-and-security.html and [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) suggest that I need both a .crt file and a .key file, but only a .crt file is provided, and seems to be all that is needed on other OSes.

How can I install the provided .crt file? (Or, what is the Ubuntu equivalent of the provided Windows/Mac instructions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.crt` file is already installed in the Firefox profile created by Windmill. No additional steps are required.

You can verify this by running Firefox through Windmill, then opening Edit (menu) | Preferences (menu option) | Advanced (tab) | Encryption (tab) | View Certificates (button) | Authorities (tab), and scrolling down the list to confirm Windmill is listed.

If for some reason it isn't (due to a bug) you could try adding it manually. [In general Linux/Ubuntu applications don't use a central resource for certificate authorities](https://serverfault.com/questions/18964/add-a-custom-certificate-authority-to-ubuntu), so you can follow the directions above and click the `Import...` button. The [Windmill CA instructions](https://github.com/windmill/windmill/wiki/SSL-Support) include links to the latest `.crt` file.

This hasn't actually solved my problem, but eliminates this as the cause and answers the question.

Comment: my original problem was because I was running `windmill firefox https://www.example.com` instead of `windmill firefox https://www.example.com ssl`