# How to configure Ubuntu as an LDAP client?

Tags: ldap, client

How to configure Ubuntu 12.04 as LDAP client with PAM modules?

Comment: Posting your configuration file in your question would help!

Answer (score 16):

The contents of this post are based on [this guide](http://naidutrk.blogspot.de/2012/03/setting-up-ldap-client-authentication.html).  It should work fine in 12.04.

1. Issue the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ldap-utils libpam-ldap libnss-ldap nslcd
   ```

   **Note**: During the installation of the above packages a dialog will pop up and ask about some LDAP configuration.  Be sure to enter the correct values for your LDAP configuration.
2. Edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (via sudo). Append "ldap" to these lines:

   ```
   #Original file looks like this 
   passwd: compat 
   group : compat  
   shadow: compat 

   #After appending "ldap" lines look like these
   passwd: compat ldap
   group : compat ldap  
   shadow: compat ldap
   ```
3. Comment out the line `rootbinddn`, I'm not sure why we need to do that.
4. Edit `/etc/pam.d/login` (via sudo) and paste:

   ```
   session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
   ```
5. Edit `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` (via sudo) and paste:

   ```
   session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
   ```
6. Issue this command:

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d nslcd enable
   ```

You should be able to log in as an LDAP user after a reboot.
If you don't reboot the machine, you must restart nscd with:

```
/etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

Likely problems and solutions:

- Logging in as an LDAP user takes a very long time (minutes):  It's very likely that nss-lap is having problems finding the user's group.  Make sure that the user is in a group recognized locally, or that the user is in a group defined in LDAP.  Make sure that, if the group is defined in LDAP, that it's a real POSIX group.
- Always check the `/var/log/auth.log` log file.  If you see "unable to contact ldap server", check whether the LDAP server is reachable and the port is open.
- Try to ping the LDAP server by name
- Try to check whether the LDAP port is open:

  - LDAP can listen on different ports, but can usually be found on 389 and 636
  - You can check that a port is open by using telnet:
  - `telnet 389` or `telnet 636`
  - If you see any characters on the console then the port is open and the LDAP server should be running.
  - If you see nothing or get an error message, either the LDAP server is not running or something (such as a firewall) is preventing the connection.

Comment: If you are using ldaps you will may also need to configure trust certificates as per http://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

Answer (score 5):

To get the home directory automatically created on login, I had to put the line:

```
session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=0022
```

into `/etc/pam.d/common-session` instead of `/etc/pam.d/login` - when I just had it in the later my home directory was not created.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install ldap-utils libpam-ldap libnss-ldapd nslcd
```

Use libnss-ldapd instead.

Per bug:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libnss-ldap/+bug/1024475

Comment: Thank you. Removing libnss-ldap and installing libnss-ldapd fixed my boot issue after trying to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the option to type in usernames, you have to modify the `lightdm configuration` with the following command:

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -m true
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding typing usernames into the ligthdm greeter, as of 16.04, the lightdm-set-defaults command is gone.

Instead, you can add the option for typing usernames to the lightdm config file. For example, create the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and add the following lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```