# user management for 10+ ubuntu machines

Tags: ldap, landscape

We have two ubuntu servers and 10 ubuntu client machines. I want to maintain all users from the server something like Active Directory in windows. Is there any GUI for maintaining and achieving such ? I have heard LDAP can be the backend but , how do I manage everything from one place?

I know about Canonical's Landscape, but I am looking more of something which is free of charge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely LDAP configuration is not for beginners, but there's some tools that makes the process a lot easier.
You can try Zentyal as server (http://doc.zentyal.org/en/directory.html), it's not hard to configure and maintain. And follow this question for client configuration: [How to configure Ubuntu as an LDAP client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127389/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-an-ldap-client)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) is an effective visual platform for maintaining entries in a directory server.