# Forcing password policies - domain user management like Active Directory

Tags: server, password, active-directory, domain-server

Good topic: [user management for 10+ ubuntu machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164632/user-management-for-10-ubuntu-machines)

**The goal**: force globally password policies on Ubuntu Desktop machines (force password change, force password complexity).

Would be good but not required - manage user accounts.

1. I do not fully like a idea of one central server that can modify every machine. Would be nice if the clients would be just pulling the changes from the server, and report theirs state.
2. I know that Point.1 is tricky, probably not easy to do. Skipping that restriction, what do You think of a central management solution? Ubuntu Landscape does not provide user management. The 'Ubuntu Domain Management Server' might be a right choice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page 
this may be the answer to that topic