# How can we connect the samba Domain server w/ LDAP backend from Ubuntu client?

Tags: networking, samba, ldap, active-directory, domain-server

I already Setup Samba Domain Controller with LDAP Backend in Ubuntu 12.04 / 13:04
See more at: http://www.unixmen.com/setup-samba-domain-controller-with-openldap-backend-in-ubuntu-13-04/#sthash.P6UnTNp7.dpuf

In that tutorial shows how to join a windows client to samba domain and it works but how we can join the ubuntu client to samba domain like windows did?

From login system using the user accounts that created from the domain server?

Comment: Take a look at [Join an Ubuntu desktop client to samba domain, and login](http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2011-March/161394.html).

Comment: Thanks Mitch I will try that one. I will post an answer if it is work.

Comment: Hello @Mitch it does not work.

Comment: It works it with LDAP-PAM. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the link below for the solution:
[How to configure Ubuntu as an LDAP client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127389/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-an-ldap-client)

Addtional - To make ldap user a sudoer:

I got it from [Ubuntu LDAP Admins and GUI Root Passwords](http://www.ossramblings.com/ubuntu-with-ldap-user-root-password-issue).

In file:

```
/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/51-ubuntu-admin.conf
```

Here's what the file looks like:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:admin
```

Simply add in your network group, separated by a semicolon:

```
[Configuration]
AdminIdentities=unix-group:admin;unix-group:Domain Admins
```