# Can't authenticate against LDAP. /etc/nsswitch.conf seems to be ignored

Tags: authentication, ldap, pam

Running ubuntu 14.0.4.1 on a BananaPi (ARM).  I've had a lot of luck getting LDAP authentication to work under 14.0.4 on x86, but something about this just isn't working.

If you run `getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | sort` I get all my local unix users, but no accounts from LDAP. Conversely, running that command on one of my x86 boxen works just fine. It's like it doesn't even consider going to LDAP.

If you try and su to an LDAP user, it fails with the following in `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi sudo: jonathanfisher : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/jonathanfisher ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/su - jonathan.fisher
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by jonathanfisher(uid=0)
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi su[627]: No passwd entry for user 'jonathan.fisher'
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi su[627]: FAILED su for jonathan.fisher by root
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi su[627]: - /dev/pts/0 root:jonathan.fisher
Nov 19 12:09:18 BananaPi sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Here's my `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file:

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis ldap
```

Any help or hints is appreciated... ESPECIALLY if anyone knows how to turn on more debug logging for the authentication stack. THANK YOU!

## EDIT

So I figured at least one thing out, this is something wrong with lib_pam.so itself, not the `nsswitch.conf` file. I did an experiment  `/etc/nsswitch.conf` modified it so it had ldap only. The boot failed of course, but it proves that the system is actually reading the file.

Again, if anyone knows how to turn on debug logging in the pam stack, that'd be fricken super.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Ubuntu as an LDAP client?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127389/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-an-ldap-client)