# Need help configuring 16.04 Xenial to auth via LDAP and PAM

Tags: server, 16.04, authentication, ldap, pam

I am trying to get Ubuntu Server 16.04 configured so I can authenticate via pam and LDAP to our Active Directory servers. I have this combination working in 14.04. Following the same configuration steps in 16.04 does not seem to work.

The setup I've used before is basically what is described in this article: [How to configure Ubuntu as an LDAP client?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127389/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-an-ldap-client)

When I configure that on a 16.04 machine and try to SSH in, what I see in the auth.log is an LDAP bind failure. The user it is trying to bind as is the user I'm logging in as, not the user I defined in ldap.conf as the bind user.

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from LDAP to SSD.

Now I have Xubuntu clients authenticating vs Active Directory without problems (can be the same with Ubuntu Server?)

I have used this guide [SSSD and Active Directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html)