# Add certificate authorities system-wide on Firefox

Tags: firefox, certificates

I want to add some root CAs that doesn't come with the default firefox on Ubuntu, but I don't know how.

I tried adding them to the local certificates with `certutil`, but it didn't work. It messed up my certificates database.

```
$ certutil -A -d .mozilla/firefox/kek3dogy.default/ -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/FNMT_ACRAIZ.crt -n "Certificado Raiz FNMT" -t "TCu,Cuw,Tuw"
```

and then

```
$ certutil -L -d .mozilla/firefox/kek3dogy.default/

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority                      ,,   
VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3                       ,,   
VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA                  ,,   
DigiCert High Assurance CA-3                                 ,,   
GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2                         ,,   
GeoTrust SSL CA                                              ,,   
StartCom Class 2 Primary Intermediate Server CA              ,,   
Google Internet Authority                                    ,,   
Certificado Raiz FNMT                                        CT,C,c
USERTrust Legacy Secure Server CA                            ,,   
HP Jetdirect 2B0EAD20                                        ,,   
Akamai Subordinate CA 3                                      ,,   
VeriSign, Inc.                                               ,,   
Thawte SGC CA                                                ,,   
VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2                       ,,
```

The certificate won't show up on Firefox. I tried this several times, even deleting the profile, and it showed up once on the Firefox interface, but completely empty.

Anyways, that's only for a user, and I want to add them system-wide. Is there a system-wide database I can modify? How?

If there is no system-wide database I can modify, I can rely on a X start script (as `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` ones, or a script called by the xdg autostart system on `/etc/xdg/autostart/`) to modify the user profile at session start, but I need a solution that works. I can't even load certificates on the user profiles from the command line now!

Comment: Is editing the default profile an option (so that newly added certificates are added when a new profile is created, but old profiles are left unchanged)?

Comment: No, approximately +100 profiles already exist and new profiles are a rare thing.

Comment: Can't you generate a new profile folder in Firefox's directory, and then add it to `profiles.ini`? Then you could add your changes to it, and then copy it and `profiles.ini` to each user directory.

Comment: N.B. You can edit profiles for Firefox by running `firefox -p` - but you have to close Firefox first.

Comment: Nope, there are +100 users with their own already existing profile. They won't like to lose their bookmarks, history, passwords, etc.

Comment: Have you tried importing the certificates from within FF?

Answer (score 31):

The problem here is that Firefox does not have a 'central' location where it looks for certificates. It just looks into the current profile. That's why modifying `/usr/share/ca-certificates` or other similar directories won't work with Firefox. This is something that has been requested for years; see issues [620373](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=620373), [449498](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449498) and [454036](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=454036) (and probably there are many others).

So you are left with just two kind of solutions: either modify each profile, or modify the behaviour of Firefox. I know this is not what you are looking for, but there are no ways because Firefox only looks at users' profiles.

Having said that, the solution I would choose is using hard or symbolic links, specifically I'd go with hardlinks. This solution is surely the easiest and probably the better, though I don't have enough information to judge.

What you have to do is basically removing each `cert8.db` and `key3.db` files for each profile and replace them with links to the "most complete" `cert8.db` and `key3.db`. If you go with hardlinks, the original `cert8.db` and `key3.db` will be indistinguishable from the new ones.

Remember to adjust permissions to fit your needs. Most likely, you will need to `chmod a+rw` so that everybody will be able to add/remove a certificate. If you want only certain users to be able to add/remove certificates, you can create a group, assign the two databases to that group and give `+w` permission just to the group.

Comment: Yup, same as I could come up with. It's a bit of a shame for Firefox, imo.

Comment: But won't overwrite that the user certificates? Aren't the user certificates stored there?

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis: well, when you delete that files you will loose the certificates. If this is what you mean with "overwriting", then yes. You should first merge all the databases into one and then proceed creating the hardlinks.

Comment: But... I don't want one user to have the personal certificates of the others! I'm talking now about their certificates, not the certificate authorities.

Comment: @JorgeSuárezdeLis: sorry, I can't understand: what are _personal certificates_?

Comment: The own personal user certificates (the ones on the first tab). Anyways, I don't know how to edit the certificates, because any attempt results on corrupted data.

Comment: I'm still confused. I see what you mean with personal certificates, however I can't understand what they have to do with your question. In your question, I can see only the terms _certificate authority_ and _CA_. Maybe it's just me who can't understand it, but please consider rewriting your question inserting the word _personal_ at least once.

Comment: I think (maybe I'm wrong) that personal certificates are also stored on `cert8.db` and `key3.db`, so the problem is your answer. I can't just link the same files for all the people. Anyways, I CAN'T generate more complete files, because `certutil` mess up the databases.

Comment: Jorge, I have re-read your question and this conversation and finally I got your point. The problem is that I misunderstood the meaning of "user certificates" in your first comment, hence the confusion. I'll think about a solution in the next days.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I would be very wary of suggesting making the shared db file across users _R/W_. I believe sqlite *doesn't* provide concurrent access, and I'm not sure if Firefox internally locks it with _named_ mutexes (i.e. across processes). Plus if this file is on network location... good luck synchronizing this sqlite! My 2 cents: share it, but in _R/O_ mode

Comment: Years is an understatement now. 7 years have passed since this answer was posted, and 2/3 of the linked issues are still open. Oldest linked issue is 12 years old now.

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way is to import the certificate into a sample firefox-profile and then copy the cert8.db to the users you want equip with the certificate.

First import the certificate by hand into the firefox profile of the sample-user. Then copy

```
/home/${USER}/.mozilla/firefox/${randomalphanum}.default/cert8.db
```

into the users firefox-profiles. That's it. If you want to make sure, that new users get the certificate automatically, copy `cert8.db` to:

```
/etc/firefox-3.0/profile
```

---

Here is an alternative way that doesn't override the existing certificates:
[bash fragment for linux systems]

```
certificateFile="MyCa.cert.pem"
certificateName="MyCA Name" 
for certDB in $(find  ~/.mozilla* ~/.thunderbird -name "cert8.db")
do
  certDir=$(dirname ${certDB});
  #log "mozilla certificate" "install '${certificateName}' in ${certDir}"
 certutil -A -n "${certificateName}" -t "TCu,Cuw,Tuw" -i ${certificateFile} -d ${certDir}
done
```

You may find certutil in the libnss3-tools package (debian/ubuntu).

See also: [Programmatic import of CA Certificate](https://web.archive.org/web/20110505054944/http://www.computer42.org/xwiki-static/exported/DevNotes/xwiki.DevNotes.Firefox.html)

Source: [Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla/2760345#2760345)

Comment: +1 but if you upvote this, you should perhaps also upvote the answers on StackOverflow which this was derived from.

Answer (score 14):

Found this solution to add certificates to firefox on ubuntu :

https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/#proxy

Simply need to add this file to :

```
/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/

touch policies.json
```

In policies.json add:

```
{
"policies": {
"Certificates": {
    "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
    "Install": [
               "somecert1.crt",
               "usr/local/share/ca-certificates/somecert1.crt"
               ]
         }
    }
}
```

The install part is first the name of the cert and then the path. And restart firefox. If something doesn't work try resetting firefox as if you have set something before it can stuck it.

This method works good without certutil.

Comment: Works fine, thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#policiesjson-15

Answer (score 11):

Contrary to popular belief, you *can* get Firefox to look at the system certificates instead its own hard-coded set.

To do this, you will want to use a package called [p11-kit](https://p11-glue.github.io/p11-glue/p11-kit.html). p11-kit provides a drop-in replacement for `libnssckbi.so`, the shared library that contains the hardcoded set of certificates. The p11-kit version instead reads the certificates from the system certificate store.

Since Firefox ships with its own version of `libnssckbi.so`, you'll need to track it down and replace it instead of the version provided in libnss3:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so.bak
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
```

Next, delete the `~/.pki` directory to get Firefox to refresh its certificate database (causing it to pull in the system certs) upon restarting Firefox. **Note:** this will delete any existing certificates in the store, so if have custom ones that you added manually, you might want to back up that folder and then re-import them.

Comment: Oh, wow, that's a bit of a hack, but +1. You may want to add a `dpkg-divert` step to avoid APT overwriting the file again when you upgrade Firefox package.

Comment: @wheeler. Do you know if this still works? I've tried it with Ubuntu 18.04 and after I perform this Firefox won't load any of the certs at all. Have p11-kit 0.23.9-2

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 (32-bit) I successfully used `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-proxy.so` (with Firefox 52.6 ESR). This did not work in Ubuntu 20.04 (64-bit), here I used `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so` according to this answer (with Firefox 78.5 ESR)

Answer (score 3):

Beginning with Firefox 64, Mozilla says, that an own "enterprise CA" can be imported from those system paths in Linux:

- `/usr/lib/mozilla/certificates`
- `/usr/lib64/mozilla/certificates`

Those paths do not exist by default in Ubuntu, but can be added manually.

Additionally, you have to name each certificate in the file `/usr/lib/firefox/distribution/policies.json`, so that it gets imported automatically:

```
{
    "policies": {
        "ImportEnterpriseRoots": true,
        "Certificates": {
            "Install": [
                "example.crt",
                "/specific/folder/another-example.crt"
            ]
       }
    }
}
```

In this case, a certificate file named "example.crt" in either of the named default directories will be added when firefox restarts.

As Batchen Regev showed in his answer, you can also point to a file with an absolute path. (This way the .NET core development server on linux is also adding the localhost certificate).

Reference:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/setting-certificate-authorities-firefox

Comment: This seems like a nice and elegant solution, unfortunately, I couldn't make it work with Firefox 91.5.0esr on Debian 11. Is there an additional step to do besides adding the `.pem` certificates to `/usr/lib/mozilla/certificates ` and settings `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` to `true` ? Is PEM (clear text) the right format to use ? Documentation on support.mozilla.org is unclear about that.

Comment: @MoonSweep:
I just tested this again, and it seams that not all files in those paths are imported automatically. You have to add them in the "Install" array of a `policies.json` file, just the way that Batchen Regev's answer describes here.
I will update my answer on this. Thanks for the question!

Comment: I just tried, and indeed, with the `policies.json` file, it works now. Thanks !

Comment: Does this still work for you?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#certificates--importenterpriseroots "Note: This policy only works on Windows and macOS. For Linux discussion, see bug 1600509."

Comment: putting config in /etc/firefox/policies/policies.json  worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I found out that most of the time and by default if not configured otherwise Firefox uses legacy security databases (cert8.db, key3.db, and secmod.db)
that means you will need to use a different command line to inject the certificate into the correct database that Firefox use. (see more from the man of certutil)

so if your system uses the default data base the command should go like this: (dbm)

```
certutil -A -n "Description Name" -t "CT,C,C" -d dbm:/home/<username>/.mozilla/firefox/<default folder>/ -i certificate.crt
```

otherwise it should be like this: (sql)

```
certutil -A -n "Description Name" -t "CT,C,C" -d sql:/home/<username>/.mozilla/firefox/<default folder>/ -i certificate.crt
```

from man certutil:

```
-d [prefix]directory
Specify the database directory containing the certificate and key
database files.

certutil supports two types of databases: the legacy security databases
(cert8.db, key3.db, and secmod.db) and new SQLite databases (cert9.db,
key4.db, and pkcs11.txt).

NSS recognizes the following prefixes:

·   sql: requests the newer database

·   dbm: requests the legacy database

If no prefix is specified the default type is retrieved from
NSS_DEFAUL
```

Comment: Using my .pem files with the first `certutil` command worked. I was looking for automating a single-user setup script and this does the trick. You'll need to `apt-get install libnss3-tools` to have `certutil`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the features of the CCK Wizard Firefox add-on is importing CA certs. I use this add-on to create a custom add-on that includes a company CA Cert. I then package the custom xpi in a .deb on the internal repository that all the workstations get updates from.

[CCK Wizard](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cck/)

EDIT: In order to package the xpi for Ubuntu, you need to create a package that includes the directory /usr/lib/firefox-addons/extensions/[addon-name@servername] and unzip the entire contents of the xpi into this directory. For instance if you name your addon foobarbaz and the server you have it set to update from (if you were to enable that function) is intranet.example.com, then the directory would be foobarbaz@intranet.example.com. I never enable the auto update, but instead update the deb in the repo.

Comment: I prefer this method over the others because it is self-contained and can include a ton of other customizations in one place. The author seems to have removed his extension from AMO though. Now he has it on his own site [here](https://mike.kaply.com/cck2), and the latest xpi is [here](https://mike.kaply.com/updates/cck2wizard/cck2wizard-latest.xpi).

Answer (score 1):

Firefox works after a clean installation. If certificate database in `cert8.db` is deleted, it is regenerated on next Firefox start. This strongly suggests that there is a system-wide default storage of CA certs.

Firefox's source code [shows](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/Makefile#L52) that built-in CA certs are in fact hard-coded into `firefox` executable. They reside in [security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt)

So there is no way to install a certificate system-wide. Beware that patching source code may bring up issues with intellectual property rights.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a "User Environment Virtualization" (UEV) application that does this for my users, but you can do this with logon scripts in Windows clients just the same.  I won't post all of the code to dynamically find the %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\%PROFILE% path, but when you do find it, you can import the scripts using some basic commands.  I am basically reading the Firefox profiles.ini file to determine the path to the Firefox profile/cert8.db.

You may want to look at using the certutil.exe application.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil

You can run logon scripts for users that automatically imports the trusted certs from a central location into the Firefox of all users on the system.

Here is the "core" of my certificate import vb script:

```
If Instr(strLine,"Path=Profiles/") Then
  arrLine = Split(strLine, "/")
  strProfile = strAppData & "\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\" & arrLine(1)
  strCertDB = strProfile & "\cert8.db"

  'Verify the DB exists, if not move to the next entry
  If objFSO.FileExists(strCertDB) Then
    'Run certutil command on this database
    strCertCommand1 = "\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\certutil\certutil.exe -A " &_
    "-n MYCA -t ""CT,C,C"" -d " & strProfile & " -i \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\MYCA_Root.cer"

    strCertCommand2 = "\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\certutil\certutil.exe -A " &_
    "-n MYSECONDCA -t ""CT,C,C"" -d " & strProfile & " -i \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\SecondCA_Root.cer"

    strCertCommand3 = "\\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\certutil\certutil.exe -A " &_
    "-n MYTHIRDCA -t ""CT,C,C"" -d " & strProfile & " -i \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME$\certs\ThirdCA_Root.cer"

    'Run the import commands for this Firefox profile
    objShell.Run("%comspec% /c " & strCertCommand1),0,TRUE
    objShell.Run("%comspec% /c " & strCertCommand2),0,TRUE
    objShell.Run("%comspec% /c " & strCertCommand3),0,TRUE
```