# Root CA certs - exporting from Windows, importing into Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, proxy, ssl, certificates

I'm behind a corporate proxy, and we have Windows PCs with root ca certs pre-installed so SSL works with the proxy. Within my PC, I'm spinning up Linux VMs for testing, and so I have a need to get those certs installed within the VM so I can hit whatever SSL URL I need (github cloning etc). I've tried a few methods to export the certs from Windows and import them into Ubuntu, but as of yet I am unable to access SSL from within the VM.

[This answer gave me the best idea for what format to export the cert in from Windows (base-64 .cer).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/642346/1204334) After I export the `.cer` files and copy them into place in the VM, I rename them with `.crt` extensions.

[This answer best sums up what I'm trying in the VM.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

After I add the certs to the `usr/share/ca-certificates` directory and run `update-ca-certificates` the certs *do* get symlinked into `/etc/ssl/certs` but still no SSL traffic.

This is on a Windows 7 host, Ubuntu 12.04 guest.

Comment: What do you mean by "no ssl traffic"?  Is firefox complaining that the cert isn't trusted?

Comment: Both Firefox & Chrome complain about loading any SSL site, and pings/github clones to HTTPS endpoints hang/fail.

Comment: I am suffering in the EXACT same scenario. This is particularly bad when working with git as all repo cloning is just blowing up.

Comment: Yeah, and I never actually got it working. Fortunately I'm not at that gig anymore, so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Necro-posting, but in case someone else encounters this:

The answer (seems to be) that Firefox uses a different certificate store mechanism, so you should add it to the user-specific firefox profile. (Can use the firefox GUI)

See [Add certificate authorities system-wide on Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox)

> The problem here is that Firefox does not have a 'central' location where it looks for certificates. It just looks into the current profile. That's why modifying /usr/share/ca-certificates or other similar directories won't work with Firefox. This is something that has been requested for years; see issues 620373, 449498 and 454036 (and probably there are many others).

So you are left with just two kind of solutions: either modify each profile, or modify the behaviour of Firefox. I know this is not what you are looking for, but there are no ways because Firefox only looks at users' profiles.