# Ubuntu Company Certificate Help

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificates

I'm new to Ubuntu and have a question.
My company uses a custom certificate which is put into the certificate chain. Having this, Firefox always asks me to add an exception and also on the terminal I can't use wget for https addresses for example.

Is there any way to make Ubuntu accept / learn to use our company's certificate?
I already tried to export the certificate from Firefox to a .crt file, copy it to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates and call update-ca-certificates, but with no success.

Any idea? If you need further information, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

---

Thanks for the comment regarding FF. Anyhow I need to solve this for the command line interface too. By the way, this is the error I get in the command line. 192.168.1.8:1357 is my “local” proxy, which communicates with the company’s Windows Proxy.

```
ubuntu-dev:~/Documents/certificates$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1204-jdbc42/postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc42.pom
--2015-10-14 16:54:44--  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/postgresql/postgresql/9.4-1204-jdbc42/postgresql-9.4-1204-jdbc42.pom
Connecting to 192.168.1.8:1357... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify repo1.maven.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=MYCOMP,OU=Departx,O=MYCOMP,C=AT’:
Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to repo1.maven.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
ubuntu-dev:~/Documents/certificates$
```

Comment: This seems to show a correct method (2 bounties awared) for FF and has a mention of FF using its own database: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox In the generic one there is this comment about FF too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate#comment902251_94861

Comment: First, thanks for your comment. I could fix the issue for FF now. I've edited my initial post, since my problem is not FF related only. But thanks for your hints regarding FF.