# Add trusted root CA globally

Tags: firefox, chromium, ssl, certificates

I am behind corporate proxy that replaces root CA certificates on some websites. I did

```
cp corporate-certs/*.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/corp
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

I do see that `update-ca-certificates` found out new certificates and created new links.

That did resolve the corporate website certificate resolution. However, I still get error when accessing public website with substituted root CA certificates that the certificate is untrusted. However when I add them manually the browser (the same certificates that were copied) as trusted authorities. This is both true for Firefox and Chromium browser. I wonder why the browser just don't pick up them from the OS source? Am I missing some steps?

Comment: Firefox at least used its own NSS trust store, and perhaps Chromium has moved to the same setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add certificate authorities system-wide on Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox)

Comment: @muru thank you. Regarding firefox I suspected something like this. What about Chromium? I though it does use system-wide certificates?

Comment: So it was, but it seems they too have started using NSS according to https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/cert_management.md