# Is it possible to disable a Certificate Authority system-wide or at least on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, security, certificates, tls

I want to disable CAs that are under control of a country that's waging war against mine, how can I do it? I see one right away. The question still stands even if you are convinced there are none, it's not about whether there are matching CAs.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

Doesn't show the Yandex CA that's listed on `about:certificate` page in Firefox and there is no way do disable it there, unfortunately. It was issued by `Unizeto Technologies S.A.`, Poland and this one is listed in the `ca-certificates` list.

Comment: Are you certain the Yandex CA is in ca-certificates?  It might be independently in the firefox cert store which is different from system ca-certificates and can only be managed within Firefox.  Some details about where you are seeing the CA cert listed will help.

Comment: Reviewers and Flaggers: **Regardless of the current geopolitical climate**, this question is not offtopic, nor rude or abusive, nor "opinion based" and can be rewritten to "How do I disable a given CA cert system-wide".  This does not require closing at this time.

Comment: Firefox has its own cert store independent of the system CAs.  You have to remove/disable certs in the Firefox cert store from within firefox and its certificates panel in settings.

Comment: It's a bit late here and I don't see a way to disable it through Firefox, unfortunately. Thank you, I'll be back after resting for some time.

Comment: There is a good answer to this questions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036637/695857)... So I would vote to close this, because it is a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add certificate authorities system-wide on Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox)

Comment: @SimonSudler almost, thank you. See the answer I've added, please copy it to close this question sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Remove unwanted certificate in local Firefox user profile

Sure thing, I will copy the answer... To remove a unwanted root CA from your personal Firefox certificate store, you have to install `libnss3-tools` and remove the unwanted root CA via `certutil`

```
$ sudo apt install libnss3-tools --yes
$ certutil -D -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/{profile}/ -n "{CA nickname}"
```

However I want to focus on the much more generic, user agnostic and system wide solution.

#### Use system wide certificate store for all Firefox users (and remove un-trusted root CA for everyone)

By default, Firefox uses its own certificate store, which contains hard-coded root CAs. On the first start, these certificates are copied into the users Firefox profile. For these builtin certificates a `PKCS-11` module is used:

[image: Firefox default PKCS-11]

These build in `PKCS-11` module can be changed by replacing the Firefox `libnssckbi.so` library with the `p11-kit` library.

```
$ sudo apt install p11-kit --yes
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so.backup
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
$ sudo dpkg-divert --package firefox --add --rename \
  --divert /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so.backup /usr/lib/firefox/libnssckbi.so
```

In short:

- Install `p11-kit` package
- Move default `PKCS-11` device library from `libnssckbi.so` to `libnssckbi.so.backup`
- Create link to `p11-kit` library for `libnssckbi.so`
- Register package diversion, to avoid link replacement, when Firefox receives an update

After these steps restart Firefox and checkout the `PKCS-11` module and the registered root CAs:

[image: p11-kit module]

If the trusted root CAs are modified by `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`, all Firefox instances will be affected immediately.

Answer (score 2):

The suggested question helped but answers there do not contain the relevant example:

```
sudo apt install libnss3-tools
certutil -D -d ~/.mozilla/firefox/{profile}/ -n "{CA nickname}"
```

Simon, can you please copy this answer with any modifications and I'll mark it as solved?