# Web browsers can't find my certificates on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04, certificates

I've tried the following applications:

- Firefox (Snap)
- Vivaldi (DEB)
- Edge (Flatpak)

I put the root and immediate certificate crt files in `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/`, and ran `update-ca-certificates`, and no dice. I did try to manually import on my Firefox (snap) using the same certificates and that worked.

Edge (Flatpak) on my Rocky Linux 9 works fine when I do `update-ca-trust` using the same certificates.

The only difference between the one in RL9 & Ubuntu is that I had to split one of the certificates in Ubuntu due to it skipping, but otherwise,  they're the same.

Comment: Browser certificates are stored in `~/.pki`

Comment: But I want them to be accessible system-wide @DanielT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add certificate authorities system-wide on Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244582/add-certificate-authorities-system-wide-on-firefox)

Comment: @DanielT sort of.  I can deal with Firefox's oddities some other time.  But I wanna apply it system-wide for all browser.  Most of my stuff at work need Chromium-based, and our deployments have Chrome pre-installed because of that.

I personally use Brave or Vivaldi on my custom Ubuntu desktop at work (we're still on 20.04, while I'm on 22.04 for testing).

Comment: My Chrome changes my Firefox's certificates when I edit them in Chrome settings. I don't have snaps or flatpaks. You can symlink that directory in the default user profile by adding a symlink in `/etc/skel`

Comment: But I'm doing this on corporate environment.