# Problems using Murmur with self-signed certificate

Tags: certificates, mumble, murmur, self-signed

I made my own CA using `openssl` and sign other certificates using that Root certificate. I signed a certificate using my CA for use with my Murmur server, and have the following in `/etc/mumble-server.ini`:

```
sslCert=/etc/ssl/localcerts/murmur.crt
sslKey=/etc/ssl/localcerts/murmur.key
```

The permissions on those files are as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root          8.3K May 10 00:01 murmur.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root mumble-server 1.7K May  9 23:37 murmur.key
```

There are no errors about loading the certs in the server logs, but whenever I try to connect to the server I get the following error in the client and on the server in `/var/log/mumble-server/mumble-server.log`:

```
SSL Error: No certificates could be verified
```

How do I get Murmur working with a self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Murmur does not automatically trust the certificates you tell it to use. When it looked at my Murmur certificate, validation failed since I never trusted my personal CA on the server itself. So I just had to trust it on the server by following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/94861/205638) and now everything works perfectly.