# Root certificate issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, ssl, certificates

I am configuring a new web application server running Ubuntu 16.04.  The only thing "unusual" I have done is install php 5.6 instead of php7.  Php5.6 however does require a valid root certificate and I am getting errors in a variety of apps that care about this.  Curl, cron, etc.

I have tried a variety of fixes to get this resolved with no improvement.  Such as:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3346#issuecomment-76593763

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821245/github-server-certificate-verification-failed/35824116#35824116

[How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate/94861#94861)

Still no luck.  The cron job I am running still generates:

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
```

More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
>    of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
>    bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>    using the --cacert option.
>
> If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
>    the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
>    problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
>    not match the domain name in the URL).
>
> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
>    the -k (or --insecure) option.

Comment: Try this https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be for self signed certificates, and I thought I understood that they are to be avoided.  That page in fact says as much.  Is this really what I want to do?  It's a production server.

Comment: You tried installing a commercial cert I suppose?

Comment: I tried following the steps in the instructions I pasted into the original question; one of these included getting a .pem from curl.haxx.se, which I wouldn't call "commercial" I guess but not self signed either(?).  This is what has me confused.  I've installed dozens of commercial certs on dozens of web *sites*, but I've never had to jump through hoops with certs just to get basic php services to run.  I don't really know what's needed.  Seems very strange to me that a commercial cert would be needed just to get php to run.

Comment: Yes I agree its indeed strange and new to me.

Comment: Just to clarify, then, I have a cert installed on a web *site* that is not self signed... it is a letsencrypt cert... and that site has issues connecting to the smtp service via API, and the error message suggests it's a root cert issue, same as with my cron curl error.  In fact I am betting the API call uses curl.  So a "real" web *site* cert doesn't solve the problem.  It seems php demands a root *server* cert is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check the validity of the web server certificate . The steps you describe are correct, but let's get the facts about the certificate.

The steps below, I use for troubleshooting the web server certificate.

- Check if the server name you expect is in the /CN option in subject:

(SERVER_COMMON_NAME is the webserver who you want to contact)

```
 echo | openssl s_client -servername ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME} \
    -connect ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME}:443 2>/dev/null | \
    openssl x509 -noout -subject
```

Check if the CA is the one you expect (the supplier of the    cerficate):

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME} \
            -connect ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME}:443 2>/dev/null | \
        openssl x509 -noout -issuer
```

Check the /CN field in issuer line.

- Check the dates of the certificate

```
echo | openssl s_client -servername ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME} \
        -connect ${SERVER_COMMON_NAME}:443 2> /dev/null | \
        openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Check the 'notBefore' and 'notAfter' results.

- If the above looks good, then test with curl AND specifing the CA root certificate file:

  curl --cacert certs/the_ca.cert.pem -I https://${SERVER_COMMON_NAME}:443

If --cacert option works then check if the CA-root file is system wide known.

Ommit the --cacert.
If curl gives an error, then the ca-root-file is NOT installed in the system ca-certificates directory.