# Adding a certificate to Ubuntu

Tags: ssl, certificates, letsencrypt

I am having with an App that is not serving the intermediate certificate to the clients.

As a workaround I wanted to add the intermediate certificate (Let's Encrypt X3) to the ca-certificates and followed the steps described over here: [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Unfortunately, I am getting this error:

> syntax error at /usr/local/bin/c_rehash line 15, near “= ;”
>
> syntax error at /usr/local/bin/c_rehash line 16, near “= ;”
>
> Execution of /usr/local/bin/c_rehash aborted due to compilation errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To install a Let's Encrypt certificate, use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutzesty-apache) utility. It is well documented.

You simple have to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt install python-certbot-apache 
sudo certbot
```

Comment: I already have certbot installed and a Let's Encrypt certificate successfully created.

The problem I have is that when I do curl https://domain:port -v I get this output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sRKzpFP4yn/

I can solve this issue by pointing to the lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem that is provided by Let’s Encrypt over here: https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

The output of curl https://domain:8920/ --cacert /tmp/lets-encrypt-x3-cross-signed.pem -v looks like this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rCDSm5vbvJ/

What I want to do know is to add the cross signed cert to the root ones.

Comment: You need to verify your certificate installation. The output of curl is not expected for a successful installation.

Comment: don't forget to run sudo apt-get update before `sudo apt install python-certbot-apache` or it might give you a `couldn't locate` error

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong.  The c_rehash perl script which is being executed was not built correctly during the openssl installation.

If you open c_rehash, you can see the lines with the errors.  The built script does not have any values set, the "= ;" code.  This causes the error.

man c_rehash to see what it does.  In short, it hashes the .crt/.pem files in the default directory and generates symlinks which point to the .crt/.pem files.  Why?  Some programs use these hashes rather than the actual name.

You can find the default directory that openssl has configured (installation directory)  using the 'openssl version -a' command and look at the OPENSSLDIR.  Use this value in the c_rehash perl script (make sure to surround with double quotes) for both $dir and $prefix.

I don't know why the build script did not work correctly during the installation; probably a bug fixed in a later release.  I was on 1.0.2o.