# How do I install an SSL certificate in order to serve a local web application?

Tags: browser, ssl, certificates, https, javascript

I need to install a local SSL certificate so that the browser trusts it. The tutorial [Running Angular CLI over HTTPS with a Trusted Certificate](https://medium.com/@rubenvermeulen/running-angular-cli-over-https-with-a-trusted-certificate-4a0d5f92747a) has instructions for OS X and Windows, but not Ubuntu.

For example these are the instructions for OS X:

> 1. Double click on the certificate (`server.crt`)
> 2. Select your desired keychain (`login` should suffice)
> 3. Add the certificate
> 4. Open Keychain Access if it isn’t already open
> 5. Select the keychain you chose earlier
> 6. You should see the certificate `localhost`
> 7. Double click on the certificate
> 8. Expand **Trust**
> 9. Select the option **Always Trust** in "When using this certificate"
> 10. Close the certificate window
>
> The certificate is now installed.

What would the equivalent be for Ubuntu?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:
[How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)

Also these explanations are about a self-signing certificate and not about a CA (certificate Authority)on a server Apache!

To install openssl:

```
apt-get install openssl
```

To generate the private key:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out certificat.key 4096
```

We rename the key :

```
mv certificat.key certificat.key.lock
```

Then generate our unlocked certificate:

```
openssl rsa -in certificat.key.lock -out certificat.key
```

Private key unlocked : certificat.key

Locked private key : certificat.key.lock

Generation of the signature request file:

```
openssl req -new -key certificat.key.lock -out certificat.csr
```

To auto-sign your certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in certificat.csr -signkey certificat.key.lock -out certificat.crt
```

With Apache:

```
a2enmod ssl

/etc/apache2/site-availables/tuto.conf
```

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName      tuto.myaddrsite.com
>     # Redirect HTTP port to HTTPS port
>     Redirect        / https://www.myaddrsite.com
> </VirtualHost>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>     ServerName      tuto.myaddrsite.com
>     DocumentRoot    /var/www/tuto
>
>     SSLEngine on
>     SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/www/certificat.crt
>     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/www/certificat.key
>     SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
>     SSLHonorCipherOrder on
>     SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

To activate vHost :

```
a2ensite tuto.conf

service apache2 restart
```

After that, I don't know how to proceed with Angular. 
My description is for Apache, but you always could find some interesting descritption by simple search on your browser. Or maybe somebody will coming to complete my description :)