# Installation of intermediate certificate not working for command line tools

Tags: 18.04, wget, curl, certificates

**TL;DR:** No description on how to install a intermediate certificate works under Ubuntu 18.04. Any suggestions?


Before marking this as a duplicate of [How do I install a root certificate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate)
or any other instruction on installing certificates, please read my problem and try to find a solution.

I tried to install the certificate of my proxy an a Ubuntu 18.04 machine in every combination of steps possible:
**Step 1:** Download the proxy certificate via firefox warning in PEM-format (-----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE-----). It is the intermediate certifcate of the proxy signed by a root CA.
**Step 2:** Either just nename the file (`mv proxy.pem proxy.crt`) or doing this with openssl (`openssl x509 -outform PEM -in proxy.pem -out proxy.crt`). Now I have a certificate with `.crt` ending and PEM-format as told by [Installing a root CA certificate in the trust store](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store). I also tried DER format, but neither worked.
**Step 3:** Copying the certificate to `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` or `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` 
**Step 4:** Using `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` or `update-ca-certificates` to update the certificate store 
**Step 5:** Check `/etc/ssl/certs/`, if proxy certificate is there. There are always two links like:

```
15af16f2.0 -> proxy.pem
proxy.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/proxy.crt
```

The path to the certificate is always correct, but can also be `/usr/local/...` depending on previous step.


In my opinion the certificate should be installed and working. But when I try to connect to any website via `wget` or `curl`, they both create errrors:
**wget:**

```
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=......': unable to get issuer certificate
```

**curl:**

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to connect to get issuer certificate
```

It isn't even working with `wget --ca-certificate=/path/to/proxy.pem https://www.google.com`

However `apt` has one `https:\\...` repo and is working.
The installation of the same certificate on Ubuntu 20.04 was working like a charm.
The software is up to date on all instances.

Any suggestions on what to try next, where to look for more information, or my error in the process?